# Linux sort with 'nested' fields

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line, gnu-sort

I have a big file with lines of the following format:

```
field1:field2:field3:field4:field5
```

I want to sort on `field4`. However, `field4` itself is 'subdivided' like this:

```
field41_field42_field43_field44
```

The command to sort `field4` is

```
sort -t_ -k1,1d -k2,2g -k3,3g -k4,4g
```

So what I have to do is split each line by `:` and then split the fourth field by `_` and perform the specified sorting on it. Is there an easy way to do this?

A small subset of the data can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/GzQP8cEy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this myself - you could perform a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) by temporarily copying the fourth field to the beginning of the record, sort by it, and then remove it

```
awk -F':' -vOFS=':' '{print $4,$0}' file | 
sort -k1,1d -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n -t"_" | 
cut -f2- -d":"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works quite well. I made some errors in my initial post, so I updated to 'field4' and corrected the sort key.
This does not affect the correctness of your answer, though.
I will accept your answer soon, I doubt anyone will come up with an easier solution.

Comment: @feob, thanks, updated my code to reflect the change from 3rd to 4th field